# Showing Categories in WordPress loop

Tags: wordpress, post, thumbnails, show, categories

HI I have added a loop code to a WP page to display a list of thumb of posts.
It works fine, but it shows each post I have published, even if isn't in the categories choosen. It's a problem because some posts shouldn't be showed!
Could you help me please?

```
<?php  $posts = get_posts('category=Products&numberposts=-1'); 
            foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                ?><li><div class="fotoBoxContent"><a class="fotoBox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); the_title(); ?></a></div></li>
            <?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Posts of category "Products" are showed, posts of categories child of "Products" are showed too, but are showed posts of other categories including "uncategorized".

PS: is printed, below the title of the page, "cat : 11,10,13,14,16,9,12, | " there is method to avoid this printing? thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Is "Products" the actual slug of the category you're trying to grab? I would double-check that. You want the category's slug, not its display name.

Comment: the slug is products too, I tried rename the slug with "pro" but nothing happened.

Comment: Is the products slug "Products" or "products"? I believe it's case sensitive.

Comment: no it was products all lowcase, and changed to prod to try a different name, but it's the same.

Comment: It's not clear from your comment, but in the get_posts query, did you change the word products to be lower case or not?

Comment: yes I changed... however not I have solved, I should put there the category ID not the category's name! Now I need to remove the categories list

Answer (score 0):

The category has to be the ID not the name. Also, try setting up the `get_posts()` using an arguments array instead of doing it inline:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'category' => '*ID*',
'numberposts' => -1
);

$posts = get_posts($args); 
foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li>
       <div class="fotoBoxContent">
       <a class="fotoBox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
       <?php the_post_thumbnail(); the_title(); ?>
       </a>
       </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

From WordPress Codex - **Note:** The category parameter needs to be the ID of the category, and not the category name. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts